# Control transition with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, transition

I have made a drop down menu with CSS using the `#nav:hover` selector to activate the property and value `transition:height`

http://jsfiddle.net/bryank/WXAcm/

What I really want to happen: 
when user clicks(as opposed to hover) the area activated by `#nav:hover` once the menu drops and stays dropped. Then if the same `#nav:hover` area is clicked again the menu contracts.

After some research, what I understand so far, I believe I need to use javascript. I know very little javascript beyond the most basic of basic fundamentals. Im am currently digging through all the relevant javascript I can find, and I think I have bits and pieces to the puzzle... but nothing functioning yet... anyone know a clear and concise way of making this happen ?

Comment: can jquery be part of a solution ?

Comment: sure! definitely. Thanks

Comment: You might be able to use the `:active` pseudo selector and might not need Javascript

Comment: You can do this without JS. Just need some fancy CSS tricks.

Comment: I think with the :active selector you would have to click somewhere other then the active area to retract the menu?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a CSS only solution:

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/k7HqE/

*HTML*

```
<!-- This is what is clicked, you can rework it to wrap the #nav if want -->
<label for="toggler">CLICK ME</label>

<!-- Hidden checkbox that gets toggled when the `label` is clicked -->
<input id="toggler" type="checkbox">

<!-- Your unmodified nav -->
<div id="nav">
    <!--logo_image--> <a class="bg" href="#"><img src="b&w_logo.jpeg" height="56" width="110" /></a>

    <!---->
    <div style="height:1em;"></div>
    <div style="font-size:1.1em;"><b>Artists</b>
    </div>
    <div style="height:1em;"></div>
    <!---- AND SO ON ---->
</div>
```

*CSS*

```css
/* hide the input */
#toggler { display: none; }

/* transition based on input checked state */
input:checked + #nav {
    height:39em;
}
```

Comment: Oooo very clever. Have a +1!

Comment: works perfect, clever CSS trickery. I am still very new to CSS/javascript. are there any browser related issues or other reasons to do this with CSS instead of JS or vise versa?  P.S my 'reputation' wont allow me to +1 answers just yet :/

Comment: @BryanK: Any browser that supports CSS3 `transition` will also support `:checked`, so it should work in all the same browsers where your `:hover` version worked.

Comment: I was toying with this and discovered I can put my #nav div inside the label tag... works great. Thanks again bojongles

Comment: @BryanK: You're welcome. And yes, as long as `label` has `display:block;` it should work that way.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have something :

Javascript :

```
document.querySelector("#nav").onclick = function(evt){
    var arClass = this.className.split(" ");
    if(arClass.indexOf("active")>=0){
        this.className = "";   
    } else {
        this.className = "active";
    }
};
```

**NOTES**

- `indexOf` may not work in every browser (IE7 & IE8).
- This function will replace all your classes on `#nav`.

CSS :

```
#nav:hover,#nav.active{
   height:39em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JFjwJ/

Comment: awesome! I took out `#nav:hover` and it does exactly what I want. Thanks YoaanM

Comment: You're very welcome. Just be aware that `indexOf` may not work in every browsers (Yeah I'm looking at you IE7 & IE8).

Comment: This works perfect in jsFiddle, I think I need to use an "onLoad" event in some manner to get it to activate as internal script on my html page? Thanks again for the help

Comment: i used this and it worked... window.onload = menuNav; function menuNav{ followed by your code.